# Cleaner replacement method in powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

I have written the following code in powershell and I think there is a better way to replace strings in a given file

```
$(Get-content $output_file) -replace $regex2,'' | set-content $output_file
$(Get-content $output_file) -replace '_','(' | set-content $output_file 
$(Get-content $output_file) -replace '"',')' | set-content $output_file
```

The first replace is for a regex - which is ok.
However in the second and third instances I'm replacing an "_" and replacing a "quote"  with open and close parenthesis respectively.

Is there a cleaner way to write this code?

Comment: Better parsing with the [original RegEx](https://superuser.com/questions/1201251/text-manipulation-in-powershell/1201290#1201290) would avoid this circumvention. Why do you use two different profiles?

Comment: On the SE network you can be a member of SU and SO at the same time.  They are [not different profiles](https://superuser.com/users/345527/prasanna?tab=profile). Sometimes the answers from two different sites can give you a better perspective to resolve your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine them to avoid reading and saving the file multiple times + easier to read (in my opinion). Ex:

```
(Get-content $output_file) -replace $regex2 -replace '_', '(' -replace '"', ')' | set-content $output_file
```

Comment: If you know of a better solution, you can post it please